# Is the Sobel Filter meant to be normalized?

Tags: image-processing, discrete-mathematics

The x-derivative Sobel looks that way:

```
-1 0 +1
-2 0 +2
-1 0 +1
```

Lets say there are two samples of my image which look like that (0=black, 1=white):

```
0 0 1            1 0 0
0 0 1      &     1 0 0
0 0 1            1 0 0
```

If I perform convolution I'll end up with 4 and -4 respectively.

So my natural response would be to normalize the result by 8 and translate it by 0.5
- is that correct?
(I am wondering as can't find Wikipedia etc. mentioning any normalization)

**EDIT:**
I use the Sobel Filter to create a 2D Structure Tensor (with the derivatives dX and dY):

```
                   A B 
Structure Tensor = C D

with  A = dx^2 
      B = dx*dy
      C = dx*dy 
      D = dy^2
```

Ultimately I want to store the result in [0,1], but right now I'm just wondering if I have to normalize the Sobel result (by default, not just in order to store it) or not, i.e.:

```
A = dx*dx 
//OR
A = (dx/8.0)*(dx/8.0)
//OR
A = (dx/8.0+0.5)*(dx/8.0+0.5)
```

Comment: it only depends on your application. If the goal is to store it and visualize the result as a bitmap, then you should translate and scale so that it falls within 0..255. What is your goal ?

Comment: "So my natural response would be to normalize the result by 8 and translate it by 0.5 - is that correct?" Your response to what?

Comment: @WhitAngl: storing and visualizing is the ultimate goal (so I'll do the appropriate normalization/translation in the end), but I have to do a bit more calculation in between. And I am wondering if the Sobel Filter ALWAYS has to be normalized (see updated question).

Comment: @Lajos Arpad: Natural response to getting results which are no longer in the range of the input, i.e. [0=black to 1=white]

Comment: if the question is: does it *ALWAYS* have to be normalized, the answer is no. For example, I have an application that does not do that. Hence "always" does not hold.

Comment: I just saw your edit: if you want to compute the structure tensor: you should NOT normalize it at all.

Comment: Ok, no normalization until the very end. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you're already thinking this, but I would assume that it is ALWAYS going to be normalized and for every image know the max/min of the resulting values and scale it accordingly. Have that be part of the process for every image, and it it so happens that the max and min are 1 and 0, so be it, no scaling needed.

Comment: The only reason you would ever normalize any convolution is either because I want to see the results, or the algorithm calls for normalization. If you're just using the coefficients produced for some further computation than there's no reason to normalize.

Comment: I’d like to stick to the mathematically precise gradient magnitudes. I’m going to divide them by 8, because that is the denominator, the delta in the very formula.

Answer (score 7):

The Sobel filter is the composition of a finite difference filter in one dimension:

```
[ 1  0  -1 ] / 2
```

and a smoothing filter in the other dimension:

```
[ 1  2  1 ] / 4
```

Therefore, the proper normalization to the kernel as typically defined is 1/8.

This normalization is required when a correct estimate of the derivative is needed. When computing the gradient magnitude for detecting edges, the scaling is irrelevant. This is why often the Sobel filter is implemented without the 1/8 normalization.

The 1/4 in the smoothing filter is to normalize it to 1. The 1/2 in the finite difference filter comes from the distance between the two pixels compared. The derivative is defined as the limit of *h* to zero of [*f*(*x*+*h*)-*f*(*x*)]/*h*. For the finite difference approximation, we can choose *h*=1, leading to a filter `[1,-1]`, or *h*=2, leading to the filter above. The advantage with *h*=2 is that the filter is symmetric, with *h*=1 you end up computing the derivative in the middle between the two pixels, thus the result is shifted by half a pixel.

Answer (score 1):

A mathematically correct normalization for the Sobel filter is 1/8, because it brings the result to the natural units of one gray-level per pixel. But in practical programming, this isn't necessarily the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The structure tensor is made of sums of products, so the normalization to [0, 1] is not really helpful.

You mainly use the Eigenvalues, possibly comparing them to a threshold. Rather than normalizing all values, it is more efficient to adjust the threshold.

The ratios of the coefficients or of the Eigenvalues are normalization-independent.

---

Now if you want to store the Sobel components and your pixel data type is unsigned bytes [0, 255], the range of the components will be [-1020, 1020], which you rescale to [0, 255] by adding 1024 and dividing by 8.

If you only need to store the gradient modulus (L∞ norm), the range is [0, 1020] and a division by 4 is enough.

---

Final remark: the Sobel components are usually small, except along strong edges. So it can make sense, to preserve accuracy, to use a smaller denominator (1, 2 or 4) and clamp the values that are out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the finite difference filter in the highest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73788669/13024105) by @CrisLuengo, it is normalizing the range to be stored in an unsigned char from `[0, 255]`. When visualizing the Sobel X or Y filter output on an image, it is common practice to normalize the values to `[0, 255]` for display purposes since standard imaging tools and formats, like PNG or JPEG, do not handle negative pixel values.

However, the output of a Sobel should be in the range of `[-255,255]`. Allowing negative values is critical if you want to obtain the orientation of a derivative.

So, for Gradient Magnitude, just

```
[ 1  0  -1 ]
```

Comment: No, I did not suggest any form of normalization for the result to fit in an 8-bit range. The division by 2 in the derivative is for the actual computation of the derivative. If you use `[1,0,-1]`, then the result is double the actual derivative. The derivative is given by (f(x+h)-f(x))/h, in the limit for h to 0. Because we can't make h so small, we can pick h=1, leading to the `[1,-1]` filter, or h=2, leading to `[1,0,-1]/2`.

Answer (score -1):

Sobel filter is sort of heuristic approach to do differential along horizontally or vertically. Therefore, normalization could be arbitrary. I found following normalization makes more sense than others, which take half of the sum of absolute values.

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14434&start=30

In fact, scikit-image uses this approach. e.g.,

```
>>>from skimage import filters
>>>import numpy as np
>>>one[:,0] = 2
>>>one
array([[ 2.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.]])
>>>filters.sobel_v(one)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```