# Why the orientation of image convolution operators are not intuitive?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, imagefilter

Thanks for reading this and please excuse my poor English since I'm not a native speaker.

For example, Sobel operator:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

The right side is positive and the left side is negative in Gx, while the upper is positive in Gy.

I'm not a specialist of image processing. But I presume most people count pixels from left-upper of an image. Since we need to "flip" the kernel during the process of convolutions, why Gx is not a mirrored one for a better regularity when defining the operators?

I know technically it's not a programming question. But it's related to programming.
For example, python's `scipy.ndimage` provides the `sobel` function. That function uses a kernel that the left column is positive and the right column is negative. It differs from all materials about image processing I can find (including Wikipedia articles). Is there any special reasons that a real implementation differs from the mathematical definition?

Comment: What is your **programming** question?

Comment: The link does not say what Y convention they use. Use F(X+1,Y)-F(X-1,Y) and F(X,Y+1)-F(X,Y-1) whatever the orientation convention.

Comment: @Taosique Sorry to confuse you. I added an example in SciPy to describe my question more clearly.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks. And that's my point. I like the way of SciPy.

Comment: Wikipedia is wrong, and it’s often wrong about details. Rando’s writing and changing things can be quite useful, but you must always consult the source texts because rando’s often don’t know what they’re talking about.

Answer (score 2):

First off, let me rephrase your question slightly:

Why does `scipy.ndimage`'s version of the Sobel operator seem to be reversed from the definition given on Wikipedia?

Here's a side-by-side comparison to show the differences.  For the input, we're using the bike image in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bikesgray.jpg

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

# Note that if we leave this as unsigned integers  we'll have problems with
# underflow anywhere the gradient is negative. Therefore, we'll cast as floats.
z = ndimage.imread('Bikesgray.jpg').astype(float)

# Wikipedia Definition of the x-direction Sobel operator...
kernel = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                   [-2, 0, 2],
                   [-1, 0, 1]], dtype=float)
sobel_wiki = ndimage.convolve(z, kernel)

# Scipy.ndimage version of the x-direction Sobel operator...
sobel_scipy = ndimage.sobel(z, axis=1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15), nrows=3)
axes[0].set(title='Original')
axes[0].imshow(z, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')

axes[1].set(title='Wikipedia Definition')
axes[1].imshow(sobel_wiki, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')

axes[2].set(title='Scipy.ndimage Definition')
axes[2].imshow(sobel_scipy, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

Notice that the values are effectively flipped.

[image]

---

The logic behind this is that the Sobel filter is basically a gradient operator (`numpy.gradient` is equivalent to a convolution with `[1, 0, -1]` except at the edges).  The definition given in Wikipedia gives the negative of the mathematical definition of a gradient.

For example, `numpy.gradient` gives a similar result to `scipy.ndimage`'s Sobel filter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

z = ndimage.imread('/home/jofer/Bikesgray.jpg').astype(float)

sobel = ndimage.sobel(z, 1)
gradient_y, gradient_x = np.gradient(z)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
axes[0].imshow(sobel, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
axes[0].set(title="Scipy's Sobel")

axes[1].imshow(gradient_x, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
axes[1].set(title="Numpy's Gradient")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Therefore, `scipy.ndimage` is using a convention that's consistent to what we'd expect from a mathematical gradient.

---

Quick side note: What's often referred to as a "sobel filter" is actually the gradient magnitude calculated from two sobel filters along different axes.  In `scipy.ndimage`, you'd calculate it as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

z = ndimage.imread('/home/jofer/Bikesgray.jpg').astype(float)

sobel = ndimage.generic_gradient_magnitude(z, ndimage.sobel)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(sobel, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

It also doesn't matter which convention you use in this case, as all that matters is the absolute value of the input gradients.

Regardless, for most use cases, a smoother gradient filter with an adjustable window (e.g. `ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude`) is a better choice for edge detection.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that has been fixed and unfixed many times over. That page's history is literally filled with edits that change the signs of this kernel.

If you look at [Sobel’s original derivation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Irwin-Sobel/publication/239398674_An_Isotropic_3x3_Image_Gradient_Operator/links/557e06f508aeea18b777c389/An-Isotropic-3x3-Image-Gradient-Operator.pdf), you'll see it matches the wrong kernels that were shown on Wikipedia. But Sobel was developing a neighborhood operator, not a convolution kernel as described on Wikipedia. That is, the kernels as defined by him were supposed to be applied by correlation, for convolution we would have to mirror these kernels. Sobel also worked with a vertical axis that increased upward (as opposed to the downward direction that is more or less ubiquitous nowadays), back in the day this was also quite common depending on the device used to produce the image data. So the kernels are both mirrored and flipped vertically, which results in them being flipped only horizontally. Because of symmetry, only the x derivative therefore seems wrong for a convolution operator.

I have fixed the signs in the Wikipedia page, and added an explanation for why the kernels are different in the source pointed to. I hope this puts the issue to rest.

---

As an aside, to get the magnitude of the derivative correct, one must divide the result by 8, as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55755479/7328782).