# Approximating true heightmap gradient magnitude with opencv's Sobel filter

Tags: opencv, derivative, sobel

I have an image (`cv::Mat`, type `CV_32F`) representing grid-sampled height function. The grid has constant raster `(dx,dy)` per pixel.

I would like to estimate its gradient magnitude. Using OpenCV's Sobel filter, I approximate derivatives like this:

```
dfdx=zz.Sobel(zz,cv2.CV_32F,1,0,ksize=3,scale=?)
dfdy=zz.Sobel(zz,cv2.CV_32F,0,1,ksize=3,scale=?)
gradMag=np.sqrt(dfdx**2+dfdy**2)
```

The *scale* parameter is barely documented, but looking into the source, it is used to multiply derivative kernels, i.e. the `(-1,0,1)` for finite differences. Using the 3x3 Sobel kernel, I assumed the scale should then be 1/2*dx or 1/2*dy (finite differences scehme) to obtain derivatives in true scale, but that does not seem to be the case: I was testing this on a synthetic image of hemisphere with different raster but not getting consistent results.

How is *scale* supposed to be used to incorporate raster dimensions, thus getting real derivative estimates?

Answer (score 1):

Scale must be equal 0.25, from here: [OpenCV's Sobel filter - why does it look so bad, especially compared to Gimp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444560/opencvs-sobel-filter-why-does-it-look-so-bad-especially-compared-to-gimp)

> The normalization divisor for kernels can be calculated by the following fomula:

`enter code here`f = max(abs(sumNegative), abs(sumPositive))

> where sumNegative is the sum of negative values in the kernel and sumPositive the sum of positive values in the kernel.

Comment: The scale will also depend on raster size. How?